# Creating a Hot Spot - Vmware + Usb WiFi Adapter

Tags: linux, virtualbox, wireless-access-point, hotspot

I'm looking for a Linux build (to be installed on a low spec pentium 4 with usb wifi key or a VM) that will act as a wifi router hotspot...

Looking for following functions -

Splash page with terms and condition
Speed Throttling
Logging of visited sites
Firewall that can block file sharing
Content filter for porn

Pretty much like what we can do with linksys routers on open ddwrt but on a linux box or VM

Thnks in advance guys

Answer (score 1):

[Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/) should handle most of that, including filtering and captive portal. There's  free version that does things like [protocol control](http://www.untangle.com/Protocol-Control) and [web filtering](http://www.untangle.com/Products/untangle-libitem-webfilter)